# osascript "display dialog" sometimes works and sometimes errors with "No user interaction allowed"

Tags: osx-lion, osascript

I have a small shell script running on my OSX 10.7 (Lion) macbook pro that uses `osascript` to gather input from the user. This script sometimes works perfectly, and sometimes returns `execution error: System Events got an error: No user interaction allowed. (-1713)`.

Whether it works or not is stable after rebooting my mac - if it works, it'll work until I reboot; if it doesn't work, it won't work until I reboot; when I reboot I can't predict whether it'll work or not until I try it, even if running this is the first thing I do after a reboot.

The relevant part of the script can be simulated in Terminal.app with (copy all of this and paste it into Terminal.app):

```
echo $(/usr/bin/osascript <<-'__HEREDOC__'
tell application "System Events"
  activate
  set input to display dialog "What you type here should be returned:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2
  return text returned of input as string
end tell
__HEREDOC__
)
```

If that code shows you a dialog it's working for you. If it shows a "No user interaction…" error it's not working for you. If you reboot it may swap from working to not working or back.

Google returns a couple thousand results for 'osascript "No user interaction allowed"', but I can't find others suffering the inconsistent results I'm getting. Some [suggest](http://wisevishvesh.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/applescript-execution-error-no-user-interaction-allowed-1713/) a workaround involving saving a script file and executing it from AppleScript with

```
on run {sourcefile}
tell application “AppleScript Runner”
  do script sourcefile
end tell
end run
```

… I've not tried this because it seems so very ugly. What could be causing this sometimes not to work? How would you go about troubleshooting a problem like this?